# weird bug in C (ubuntu) : unexpected behavior change due to adding debugging statements

Tags: c, debugging

I am using an existing pakcage to some complex numerical computations. What I need to do is to customize a function called "loss". The default behavior of "loss" function leads to expected final computation results. But my customization doesn't yield the expected result. So I am trying to debug it.

(1) I am customizing a function int loss(int c1, int c2) called by some other functions. First note that the default behavior is just return c1==c2 ? 0 : 4; I want to change it to:

```
double loss(int c1, int c2) {
    int v1 = map[c1];  // map is an int array
    int v2 = map[c2];

    return doSomething(v1, v2); 
}
```

The program will use the "loss" function to do some successive complex numerical computations, the final computation result is not as expected. So I want to debug the "loss" function, to make sure it works correctly.

(2) I make it as simple as:

```
 double loss(int c1, int c2) {
     int v1 = map[c1];
     int v2 = map[c2];

   [1].  return v1==v2 ? 0: 4; // this should be equivalent to [4] in my application

         // double check that different position of the array have different values
   [2].  if( (c1==c2 && v1!=v2) || (c1!=c2 && v1==v2)) {
   [3].         exit(0);  // printf("%d %d %d %d", v1, v2, c1, c2);
         }


   [4].  return c1==c2 ? 0: 4;
 }
```

Note that if I use only [4] without any other statements, that's the default behavior, which is tested to lead to expected computation results.

1. Now I first use [1], but comment [2] to [4], which is equivalent to [4] in my application. That is, I expect there is no duplicated elements in array "map". This doesn't lead to correct final computation results, which is strange, since [1]<=>[4], and I have tested [4], the final computation is correct.
2. I want to double check that [1] and [4] are equivalent, by adding [2] and [3] (of course and remove [1]). The program runs to the end, which means [3] is never executed, so it ensures that [1] and [4] are equivalent. However, the final computation becomes NOT as expected, though I didn't change the values of c1 and c2 by adding [2] and [3]. Using printf in [3] has similar problem. But for some statements it doesn't cause problem, say in the "if" body, I just use "int a = c1 + c2;", the result is correct.
3. Even more strangely, if I comment [3] (i.e., the if body does nothing), and use both [2] and [4], the final computation is as expected!

Can you help me to figure out the weird problems?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Weird problems likely mean you're abusing memory.  It might be that you're returning a pointer to a local variable, somewhere, but by the time you're accessing it again, it has been modified.  Or it could be almost anything where you're trampling over memory.  You're using a global (or at least file scope) variable `map`; are you sure you've allocated that properly.  Is this a single file of code or is it spread over multiple files?

Comment: Try disassembling the compiler's output, and compare the results.

Comment: Yes, map is a global variable. There are multiple source files. I define map in f1.h as extern int* map; then declare it in f1.c as int* map; it is allocated memory using malloc and initialized in the main function of main.c.

Comment: How can I disassembling the compiler's output? It seems pretty advanced and complex?

Comment: Suggest using assert() and perhaps some verification code to check your assumptions.

Comment: why dont you test it by dividing the conditions in [2] into two different conditions(by removing ||)...will help understand behavior more precisely

Comment: I have tried that. The problem is similar. If the if body is empty, then there is no problem. If it contains "exit()", or "printf()" statement, then the result is incorrect. However, for some statements, there is no problem, say in the "if" boday, I use int a = c1 + c2;, which doesn't cause problems!

Comment: Compile with all warnings on (`-Wall` for `gcc`) and fix the code until no more warnings are given. Then compile with debug info (`-g`for `gcc`) and run the app using a memory checker like `valgrind`.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `return v1==v2 ? 0: 4;` and not `return v1=v2 ? 0: 4;` by mistake ?  (Notice only one `=` in the second version).  Easy mistake to make and would give the results you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming `map` is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) but it's actually [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjection); that is, there are different values `c1` and `c2` such that `map[c1] == map[c2]`. This is the best explanation for what you're seeing:

- You state that using [1], i.e. `v1==v2` doesn't lead to "correct final computation results", but using [4], i.e. `c1==c2`, does.
- [2] is performing the right check as you intend, but you're probably not detecting the effect of [3] properly. Are you sure that the program runs to the end with [3] present, instead of terminating near the end? How are you telling whether [3] is run? Even if you run with [2][3][4], the result is different than [4] alone, which suggests that [3] is actually run.
- If you comment out [3] but leave [2], the program will go in the if bracket, then out and run [4] anyway, giving the equivalent output as [4] alone, as you confirm. This is all consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the "if" statement is ever be true, then [3] exit() should be executed, the program should stop, but it seems not; The second way to check this is to change [3] to print out something, it dosen't print out anything either, AND the problem remains (i.e., adding a printf statement causes incorrect result!). So I think [3] is never executed. And I did checked the array elements, it seems correct, however, I might do further checking as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I disassembling the compiler's output?

There are several ways you can choose. I'll assume the program is named `f1`.

- `objdump -S f1`
  Look for `<loss>` in the output.
- Make an assembler listing, e. g. `gcc -g -Wa,-adhln=f1.lst -O -c f1.c`
  Make sure that in place of `-O` you use the same flags as in usual compilation.
- `gdb f1`
  `(gdb) disass loss`
  When in `gdb`, you can also
  `(gdb) break loss`
  `(gdb) run`
  and
  `(gdb) step`
  through the function, provided that `-g` produced debugging information.